# Using fminunc to find an input vector

Tags: matlab, optimization

My object is following:

```
p1=tf(1,[ 1 10 ]);  p2=tf(1,[ 1 20 ]);
object=p1*p2;
```

Time is stored in vector `t=1:n`, `n` is known.

Desired system output is known, stored in vector `y_des`.

Using `[y,t]=lsim(object,u,t)`, I get time response of dynamic system to input vector `u` which I need to optimize so my error function is minimized.

Error function is following:

```
function e = err( y_des, y )
  e=0;
  for i=1:size(y_zad,1)
    e=e+( y_des(i) - y(i) )^2;
  end
end
```

How to use Matlab function `fminunc()` to optimize my input vector? I know it should look like this:

```
[x,fval]=fminunc(@err,y_des);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a cost function with one input variable, which you pass to fminunc. So you can create a anonymous function which depends on y and passes y_des to the function err.

```
cf = @(y) err(y_des, y);
[x,fval] = fminunc(cf, y_des);
```